# How can I do I/O in @safe functions in D?

Tags: d

I am learning the D programming language, and I am trying to restrict myself to the SafeD subset of it where I can. However, I noticed that the I/O functions like writeln are all @system. How do I do I/O in SafeD?

I am using LDC2 on Fedora 19 x86-64 (downloaded from the Fedora package).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't, or at least not directly. I/O requires making system calls, which means C functions, and C functions aren't going to be `@safe`. And since `writeln` currently calls `printf` underneath the hood, it *definitely* isn't going to be `@safe`, because it's trivial to do unsafe things with `printf` (like giving it `%s` and then passing it an integer instead of a string). It *might* be possible to make `writeln` `@trusted` under some circumstances, but I don't know what all would be involved with that. That would depend on how it's implemented.

It's fully expected that any non-trivial D program will use `@system` code. The trick is to isolate it. The majority of your program will hopefully be `@safe`, but sections of it are going to have to be `@system`. However, you then only have to examine a small section of your program for memory safety. Once you verify by hand that a function which calls `@system` functions is actually memory safe, you can mark it as `@trusted` and then you can use it in `@safe` code.

Unfortunately, it's also quite likely that certain core stuff in druntime and Phobos is going to be `@system` based on what it's doing with low level stuff, and not necessarily all of it has been marked with `@trusted` as it should be (e.g. `std.array.appender` might be `@system` when it should probably be able to be `@trusted` - I'm not sure what it currently is though; it probably depends on the element type of your array). So, it's likely that some improvements will need to be made to some standard library stuff in order to better support `@safe` (which is in progress, but I don't know where all of that stands right now), and you may end up having to use `@trusted` in more places right now than you will in the future. `writeln` may or may not be able to be `@safe` or `@trusted` in the future. But it definitely won't be if the types that you're using with it don't have `@safe` or `@trusted` `toString` functions, so part of whether `writeln` is `@safe` depends on what you're using it with, regardless of how it's implemented. However, it's not currently `@safe` or `@trusted` even with built-in types, so for now, you're out of luck.

If you really wanted to, you could create a wrapper for `writeln` which was `@trusted`, but you'd have to be uber careful to make sure that the code is actually memory safe - and simply creating a templated wrapper and marking it `@trusted` isn't going to cut it, because then you'd be treating it as `@safe` regardless of what type you passed to it.  So, it's probably best to just not wrap it and then mark the caller as `@trusted` if you're sure that that particular use of `writeln` is memory safe. Of course, that also highlights part of why functions like `writeln` are currently `@system` in the first place: it's often hard to write `@trusted` templated code without trusting stuff that shouldn't be trusted (because it depends on the template arguments). Attribute inference often takes care of the problem, but if templated code is doing something that needs to be `@trusted`, it becomes difficult to mark a portion of the code as `@trusted` and leave the rest to inference, especially if the template arguments are mixed in with the `@system` stuff. I expect that we'll sort it out eventually for all of the standard library stuff though.

Comment: That makes a LOT of sense - especially seeing as the worst offender in memory safety IMO (pointers) can be avoided for most code anyway (other than the actual low level functions).

Comment: @Demetri Exactly. You have `@system` code in your program, but it's isolated, and it's generally a small enough portion that it's reasonable to verify it for memory safety yourself, whereas if you didn't have `@safe` at all, you'd have to verify your whole program yourself, which is obviously much, much harder.

Comment: writefln surely could be made @ safe, except perhaps for the automatic printing of char* since there might not be a zero terminator (did that actually make it in though? Or does it just show the pointer as hex?) It doesn't *have* to use printf at all - we already have std.format.formattedWrite that does most the work, then the final call to C might as well be verified or something like fwrite() which is pretty sane. surely @ trusted at the least.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe I expect that `writeln` probably can be made safe just so long as the arguments have the appropriate `@safe` functionality (e.g. `@safe` `toString`), but it can't be simply marked as `@trusted` or `@safe`, and I don't know how easy it would be to mark the appropriate parts `@trusted` without marking parts `@trusted` that shouldn't be `@trusted`. So, depending on the implementation, it could be a bit of a pain. I expect that we can get there though.

Answer (score 5):

I think we should make writeln and friends `@trusted` - although they use low-level primitives, they do enough checking to make sure that e.g. printf does not received messed-up arguments.

Comment: you can't the to!string calls for custom classes might not be @safe

Comment: that's not necessarily a dealbreaker though, since that only happens with certain template arguments. I think attribute inference would catch those cases.

Comment: Being able to write entire programs in SafeD could be quite nice